# XNA Multisampling only for 3D

Tags: xna, c#, graphics, directx, antialiasing

I am working on a game which consists of 3D elements and a 2D GUI. I have it working properly, but I want to enable multisampling for only the 3D parts, and not the 2D Textures. Otherwise, the GUI icons become blurred.

Here is the code for my `Draw` method

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();

        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointWrap;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

        foreach (Element e in Elements)// 3D part
        {
            e.Draw(GraphicsDevice, camera);
        }

        graphics.PreferMultiSampling = false;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        UIM.Draw(GraphicsDevice, spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();//

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Using this code, I get an exception because all of my `Texture2D`s dispose for some reason.

Is there a way to change the MultiSampling in the middle of the `Draw` method?

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multisampling is a property of the backbuffer. So: no, you cannot change it mid-draw.

Where you call `ApplyChanges` you're causing the graphics device to get torn down - you should never call this during `Draw`.

One thing you could do is render your UI to a render target without multisampling. Or alternately render your 3D geometry to a render target *with* multisampling (and disable multisampling for your backbuffer).

Note the `preferredMultiSampleCount` parameter to `RenderTarget2D`'s constructor ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb200104%28v=xnagamestudio.41%29)).

It's worth pointing out that mutlisampling (as opposed to super-sampling with a linear texture filter) *shouldn't* cause your sprites to become blurry - because it only affects the edges of polygons - not their textures! ([details here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309223019/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/04/27/multisampling.aspx)).

It's possible that you've got a sub-pixel alignment problem. On that note, it might be interesting to pass `SamplerState.PointClamp` to `SpriteBatch.Begin` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used a render target for the 3D portion of the `Draw` method and the multisampling only affects that, not my sprites.